# tablesorter plugin pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, database, pagination, tablesorter

I am using the tablesorter jquery plugin for my table with database results. However, I have more than 10,000 rows to load and when the table loads it loads all 10,000 at once and then paginates the results into 10,20,30,40 results per page. Is there any way to prevent all of them loading at once or load the first 100 etc.

I have read around this forum and this question has not been asked. Please do not be mistaken I am not having trouble with displaying the number of results per page (10,20,30,40 etc.) this is with actually loading the rows on first load since I have a huge database of 10,000 rows.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you should use the code you use to return the data set?

Comment: The tablesorter plugin is not built to handle such a large number of rows, and, using only x number of rows at a time on the page requires ajax loading, which is supported by the tablesorter but not by the pagination plugin of the tablesorter. I suggest looking for another plugin to replace tablesorter.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to load 10 rows at a time and then every time you change the page, load the next 10, is that correct?

If so, I suggest looking into the [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). It has many of these features built in including paging, sorting, and asynchronous sever calls.

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking for. Initially when I load the page, it loads all of the data and then it shows only 10. This is why initially i see a very tiny scroll bar and then it becomes smaller. Could u help me without transferring to a new plugin?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the plugin you are using so I couldn't be much help in that regard. Based on what other commenters have said, I would suggest either switching to a different grid plugin or roll your own paging system. The later would probably be faster but the former would probably be easier.